# Print contents of HTML Object tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I am currently trying to create a method that calls the browser's print function to print the `document` content embedded within my page. D3.js and jQuery libraries are included already. The process why which I hope to achieve this is as follows:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var floatButton = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("class", "printbutton")

   $(".printbutton").click(function() {
        var Popup = window.open(URL);
        $(Popup.document).load(function() {
            document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].style.opacity = 1;
            window.print();
            window.close();
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <object id="Graph_Container" data="URL" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</body>
```

The issue right now is that once `window.open(URL)` is called, the script within `$(Popup.document).load` is never run. I have tried setTimeOut for once the page does load but it's made no difference (no errors in either parent page or opened page). There is no cross framing issues either as I am able to have full control of the data once it has been loaded onto my parent page by calling:

```
var root = document.getElementById("Graph_Container").contentDocument.querySelector("svg");
```

An alternative would be to parse the XML structure within `root` on my parent page so that I wouldn't need to open a new page but I have yet been able to wrap my head around that.

Any tips/ideas on how I can print the `#document` within the `object` tag would be greatly appreciated!

**Updated**

```
window.name = "PersistWindow";
$(".printbutton").click(function() {
    debugger;
    Popup = window.open(URL, "TempWindow");
    $(Popup.document).load(function() {
        Popup.document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].style.opacity = 1;
        window.print();
        window.close();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window.open()` function can take another parameter, a window name.  First, specify a name for your current window, like `window.name="persists";` and then, for the popup you could specify something like `Popup=window.open(URL, "popped");`  This will ensure that the just-opened URL doesn't replace the code you are running, and the `Popup` variable gives you access to anything you want in that popped window --use `Popup.document` to access the document object, for example.

I'm going to add this from a comment I made below.  Think of your code as being divided into two different functions.  One holds the `window.open()` instruction, and the other --let's call it "manipulator()"-- holds the code to access the document object and do things with that data.  In many cases a browser doesn't immediately do something that JavaScript tells it to do; it waits for the currently-running JavaScript function to end, before doing it.  That means you need a way of connecting the first function to the second, and the simplest way to do that is through `setTimeout()`.  For example right after calling `window.open()` you could specify `setTimeout("manipulator();", 250);`, and then do a `return` from that first function.

The `manipulator()` function would be called 1/4 second afterward, but before it runs, the browser will have performed the `window.open()` operation.  So, when the `manipulator()` function runs, inside it you will be able to access the document object of the just-opened window, and do things with that data. (Do note that this sort of thing, dividing work between different functions, is a major reason why global variables are extremely useful in JavaScript --"Popup" should be a global here.)

Comment: How does that differ from `var Popup = window.open(URL)` and then `$(Popup.document).load`? Is `Popup` just like `handl` in this case? Am I supposed to be calling by `name` as opposed to `var`?

Comment: The difference isn't in `Popup` vs `handl`; the difference is in `window.open(URL);` vs `window.open(URL, "popped");` --and ensuring "popped" is a different window-name than the name of the window that calls `window.open()`.  The default is for `window.open()` to open a new page into the existing window, which replaces the JavaScript you were running to open that new page.  I'll edit my Answer to remove `handl`.

Comment: Updated my code. The popup window is not loading until after `$(Popup.document).load` is called so the script inside `.load` is being skipped.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that.  JavaScript can tell a browser to do something, but the browser usually doesn't do it until after the JavaScript function ends, which contained the instruction to tell the browser to do something.  You should put a call to `setTimeout("manipulator();", 250);` after calling `window.open()`.  Then let that function end/return.  The "manipulator" function would be called 1/4 second afterward, and that is the function where you would access the document object of the just-opened window.

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry I didn't earlier think about the need to give the browser an opportunity to actually do what you want it to do, before you can do things that assume the browser has actually done them.