# Autogrow textareas on copy paste in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write an autogrow functionality for text area on keyup . It works perfectly in firefox and for IE8 it works, but when try and copy paste a data having a lot of white space - it doesnot grow accordingly. It is surprising as am using scroll height not character count. Below is my code

```
$("textarea").keyup(function(){ 
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > 0){
    $(this).css('height', 'auto' );
}
var elementHeight = 16;

$(this).css('overflow','scroll');
$(this).parent().css('overflow','scroll');
var height = $(this).prop('scrollHeight');
if(height >= elementHeight){
       $(this).css('height',height+'px');
}
var parentHeight = height + 10;
if($(this).attr('id')=='evidenceDetails'){
    parentHeight = parentHeight + 70;
}
$(this).parent().css('height',parentHeight+'px');

$(this).css('overflow','hidden'); 
$(this).parent().css('overflow','hidden');
});
```

Any help will highly appreciated.

Comment: Right at the start you are testing for Firefox and using the result --but there is no equivalent test for IE (and no default).

Comment: while testing we found that when we deleted all the data from text area, the height was not decreasing in firefox. hence the check. no equivalent test for ie was done, because no extra code was needed.

Comment: Providing a delay worked. Though i don't understand why. Any comments.?

Comment: I can't promise that this is relevant to your exact situation, but here is something about how delays can be necessary sometimes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496083/print-contents-of-html-object-tag-with-javascript/26498901#26498901